# Trouble with loading .so library

Tags: java, android, bass, bass.dll

I have an android project (Inellij IDEA). I've download BASS library from official site and copied content from `lib` folder to my project folder `libs/`. But when I try to load it with `System.loadLibrary("bass");`, it throws an error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip
file "/data/app/com.negi.opengltest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libbass.so"
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe, I need to change gradle config?

upd: the answer is here [un4seen.com/forum/?topic=15633.msg110256#msg110256](http://un4seen.com/forum/?topic=15633.msg110256#msg110256)

Comment: Please try http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=15633.msg110256#msg110256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution is from http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=15633.msg110256#msg110256 :

```
1 mkdir lib, then, copy armeabi to lib, the tree should be lib/armeeabi/libbass.so
2 zip lib directory: $zip -r libbass.zip lib
3 rename: $mv libbass.zip libbass.jar
4 copy libbass.jar to YourProject/Youproject/src/main/libs  ("YourProject/Youproject/src/main/" includes AndroidManifests.xml, res, java, libs)
5 add this line:
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  to your build.gradle---->dependencies
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case, it is the Crashlytics which was conflicting. when i commented below lines in build.gradle, all goes well.

```
//    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
//        transitive = true;
//    }
//    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
//        transitive = true;
//    }
```